# Removing first line of Big CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, bigdata

How should I remove the first line of a big CSV file in python?
I looked into the previous solutions in here, one was:

```
with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
    with open("updated_test.csv",'w') as f1:
        f.next() # skip header line
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

which gave me this error:

```
f.next() # skip header line
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

the other solution was:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(data[1:])
```

Which brings memory issue!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to remove the header line, Later these data will be merged and editing them will make more problem.

Comment: Why waste your time skipping the header row when you can defer doing so to when you merge your files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `f.next()` to `next(f)`

```
with open("test.csv",'r') as f, open("updated_test.csv",'w') as f1:
    next(f) # skip header line
    for line in f:
        f1.write(line)
```

Comment: Is this optimal for very large CSV files (with hundreds of thousands of rows)?

Answer (score 0):

use the **f.__next__()** instead of f.next()

documentation here:
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.**next**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__)

Comment: No, don't do this. This method is used like this: `for x in myIter: ...`.

Comment: Downvoted because a direct call to a double-underscore method is unpythonic here (they are ugly for a reason). Instead, prefer `next(f)`.

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. I am here to learn too, the method worked for me and I did not evaluate the unpythonic way

Comment: @LutzHorn:  `next(f)` is preferable. Straight-up iteration fails in the stated goal of skipping the first line.

Comment: That's not my point. I stated that `__next__()` is used behind the scene by the code in my comment. I did not post my comment as an *answer* but as a *comment* for a bad answer.

Comment: @aberna. See [PEP 3114 -- Renaming iterator.next() to iterator.__next__()](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` is probably the fastest and doesn't require a temp file, so a python wrapper would be:

```
import subprocess

def delete_first_lines(filename, line_nums):
    n = '1,{}d'.format(line_nums)
    subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-i', n, filename ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
        )
```

Comment: This answer is totally unclear. What is 'sed'? It seems like a process of some sort that you are spawning but what does it do? The code as given does not work.

Comment: sed a standard tool on any linux-like system.